# How would I make columns of a returned table equal to rows of another table, like this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, database-design

I have 3 tables like

```
         Dudes
==========================
 id |    name   
==========================
  1 |  "Marshal Mathers"
--------------------------
  2 |  "Limp Biscuit"
--------------------------


        Questions 
===========================
 id |       qtext
===========================
 1  | "What's up, dog?"
---------------------------
 2  | "C# or C++?"
---------------------------

          Answers
=======================================================
 id |  dude_id  | question_id |       atext
=======================================================
  1 |      1       |       1     |    "Nothing much"
-------------------------------------------------------
  2 |      2       |       1     |     "Oh, you know"
-------------------------------------------------------
  3 |      1       |       2     |         "C++"
--------------------------------------------------------
```

and my wish to the Make-A-Wish Foundation (Stack Overflow) is for a sproc that would in that example return

```
===========================================================
          name         |  What's up, dog?  |  C# or C++?   
===========================================================
    "Marshal Mathers"  |   "Nothing much"  |    "C++"
-----------------------------------------------------------
     "Limp Biscuit"    |   "Oh, you know"  |     NULL
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is this possible, and if so, how would it be done?

Comment: Google SO sql server pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the dynamic version of sgeddes answer. This technique is called [**dynamic crosstab**.](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/)

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @sql = 
'SELECT
    d.name' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN q.id = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), id) + ' THEN a.atext END) AS ' 
    + QUOTENAME(qtext) + CHAR(10)
FROM #Questions

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'FROM #Dudes d
LEFT JOIN #Answers a
    INNER JOIN #Questions q
        ON q.id = a.question_id
    ON a.dude_id = d.id
GROUP BY d.id, d.name
ORDER BY d.id'

PRINT(@sql)
EXEC(@sql)
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/448010)</kbd>

Comment: What is the `#` symbol for? Never seen it in the context of SQL.

Comment: That's just for the temporary tables used.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use `conditional aggregation` to `pivot` your results with an `outer join`:

```
select d.id, d.name, 
       max(case when q.id = 1 then q.qtext end) whats_up_dog,
       max(case when q.id = 2 then q.qtext end) c_sharp_plus
from dudes d
       left join answers a on d.id = a.partner_id 
       left join questions q on q.id = a.question_id
group by d.id, d.name
```

Comment: You have magic numbers, `1` and `2`, floating around there. Any way to generalize that, I'm wondering?

Comment: @SubparWebDev -- they aren't magic -- they represent the values for the question ids that you want as columns.  Question Id 1 = "What's up, dog?" per your question...  If you don't know the columns you want to return, you'll have to use `dynamic sql` to `pivot` the results.  Lots of examples on SO how to do this...